# Disable a textfield based on a autocomplete value React js - Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield, disabled-input

I have 2  fields. The first one it's an `autocomplete`. The second one is a `textfield`.
My second field is *disabled* by default. I want to change it from **disabled to enabled** every time The user types and choose one option of my `autocomplete`.

I've tried with  using `useState hook` and  `onChange` to set and update the state of the field.This does not work though.

I've tried getting the input value with a `ref` in my `autocomplete` like the following:

```
inputRef={ref => { this.inputRef = ref; }}
```

And then appling it to the  `textfield`.

Nothing has worked.

**Note:**  my autocomplete is wrapped in a controller.

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a CodeSandbox trying to fix your problem - if I understood it correctly.

Try it and see if it makes sense:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wildflower-ckjnd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Almost ! But I actually need the oposite. The non autocomplete textfield is disabled by default. I want to make it enabled when typing in the first autocomplete. I changed the state of the second field but do not know how to make it work like you did . Please re-code the sandbox again.

Comment: Weirdly it works on your code but not in mine . Check my code out https://codesandbox.io/s/disabled-enabled-inputs-iwv3f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well - if you would provide me the information on what component - in your dialog - that should be enabled/disabled based on a condition, it would help alot :)

Comment: ohh Sorry. The first text field is the autocomplete. The second textfield is an input with datepicker. The third one should act the same as the second one related to the Autocomplete. But do not worry for it.  Hope you understand! Pls Help me out

Comment: I already gave you the answer for your problem. You have not tried to implemented it - at all. ´

Comment: Anyway - i modified your sandbox a little bit and implemented the changes to your autocomplete and your date field. You can do the rest. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ganguly-thii1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235664/discussion-between-karol-and-delice).